# Where do Smart Lock for Passwords sign-in hints come from and how to customize them?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-smartlockpasswords

In Google Play Services v8.3 Google added a way to provide the user with account "hint" for logging in - A UI to select previously used emails to sign up to an app.

[image]

See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints) for more info.

I was wondering where does Google take the emails shown in that screen, testing it on my device I see some really old / unused emails that I probably previously signed in with.

Is there a way to customize it so that only emails that are set up on the device will show up in the hint screen ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Great question, I'm the product manager for Smart Lock at Google, here are the answers:

Where do the email addresses shown in the "hints" dialog come from?

- The items shown at the top of the list correspond to the email addresses for the Google Account(s) on the device, and any other email addresses from the Android Account Manager (e.g. IMAP email addresses, email address registered by Facebook app, etc.)
- Other email addresses saved with any of the Google accounts on the device are shown next, sorted by most frequent occurrence. These were either saved to Smart Lock elsewhere (e.g. in other apps) or for websites via the Chrome password manager. These entries should correspond to what's visible at passwords.google.com or chrome://settings/passwords in Chrome for the Google Accounts on the device.
- As noted, the "hint" dialog is intended to allow the user to supply an email address (as well as name or photo URL if available) with one tap to the developer's app to help sign in or sign up, allowing pre-filling of fields in sign-in or sign-up forms, or by skipping sign-in UI completely by providing the app an [ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/idtoken-auth) which can be used for backend authentication.
- Note that this dialog is displayed by Play Services and its contents cannot be read by the calling app and are private to the user; only information from an entry which is selected by the user is provided to the developer's app. This also means that the dialog text can't be customized, other than switching between Sign in and Sign up, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621905/can-i-change-the-sign-in-hints-modal-title-from-choose-an-account-to-pre-fil) for details.
- We've considered adding UI for the user to customize what's shown on the list, but in our UX testing, such a feature is rarely used and added visual complexity and opportunity for error. In practice, most users only have a few entries and since the most the common addresses are at the top, users just pick the one they want and ignore the rest. The other entries don't really cause harm, so we've opted not to make this customizable by the user for now.

That said, can the *developer* customize what's shown in the dialog?

- Yes, developer could modify the `HintRequest` to `.setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)` and `.setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(false)`, which will cause phone numbers to be shown instead, from similar sources above (from device or associated with Google Account).
- Similarly the `HintRequest` builder can be configured to show a "Sign up with" or "Sign in with" prompt rather than the default "Continue with".

Regarding only showing the email addresses on the device: if the app's authentication system is based on email address, I'd recommend keeping the complete list of email address (not just the ones on the device), since often the user's intended email address is not a Google account (e.g. a work, school, Yahoo/Hotmail, or regional email provider). As noted above, in practice, the presence of other email addresses usually helps and does not detract from task completion (user either sees the email address they are looking for, ignores the rest, or taps "None of the above" to enter something manually), and less-used email addresses work their way to the bottom over time. (experience for developers with lots of test email addresses is a bit different than end users, who typically have a short list of email addresses)

Hope that helps! Please leave a comment with any questions or feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ! demystifies a lot of stuff.

Comment: Hi @steven-soneff, I tried to use HintRequest and called `.setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)` but the Hint dialog does not show phone number inside the device. I deliberately do not set up any Google account. I have inserted working SIM card which can receive incoming calls. Is that expected?

Comment: Never mind, turned out not every phone number inside SIM card is readable. For those of you whose phone number does not show up, do this: go to Settings -> About -> Status -> SIM status. If your phone number is listed, then it will show up on "hints" dialog, otherwise it won't.

Comment: I confirm that the `setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)` isn't showing any phone numbers for some sims (a majority of sims in fact). We tested 7 sim cards and 2 emulators (Google and Genymotion). The hint dialog only showed phone numbers for 2 sim cards. It's strange that it didn't show phone numbers for the emulators, as those do indeed show a phone number in the system settings, and TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() works on the emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but there is no "hint" screen. The link you shared talks about getting credentials from one of the accounts selected from the account screen to pre-fill the sign-up form in the app.

The screen I think you are referring to is the Smart Lock account dialog (that is what I call it at least). This screen lets you select which account saved with Smart Lock you want to use within the current Google account you're using.

The screenshot you shared seems to be another dialog that is asking what Google account you want to use (which can then have multiple Smart Lock accounts aka credentials saved in it). You can tell the difference between the two screen by the title. The Smart Lock account dialog says "Choose a -app name- account saved with Google Smart Lock"

If this screen you show can be customized, then it would not be through Smart Lock, but perhaps a Google sign in API. Sorry I could not be of more help.